# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: flutter

```
for (var i in querySnapshot.docs) {
                      if (i.data()['admin'].toString().trim() ==
                          value.toString().trim()) {
                        print("AdminDetected");
                        searchCompleted = true;
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, Admin.routeName);
                        break;
                      } else if (i
                              .data()['courtWorkerEmail']
                              .toString()
                              .trim() ==
                          value.toString().trim()) {
                        print("CourtWorkerDetected");
                        searchCompleted = true;
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, CourtWorker.routeName);
                        break;
                      }
```

lib/screens/sign_in/components/sign_form.dart:112:35: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  **if (i.data()['admin'].toString().trim() ==**
  ^
  lib/screens/sign_in/components/sign_form.dart:119:38: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  **.data()['courtWorkerEmail']**
  ^

Comment: What you are trying to do? What is the code that throws this error? Your question will probably be closed. Try to improve it so we can help. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried using `i.data` instead of `i.data()`?

Comment: Have you tried simply i['admin'] and i['courtWorkerEmail']